# How do I embed a transparent SVG object inside an HTML document?

Tags: html, svg, embedding

I'm using an SVG object embedded in HTML using the `<object>` tag. The SVG gets painted with a white background. How can I get rid of it and make the element transparent so that the HTML background shows through.

There is supposed to be a way to do this in IE with Adobe's SVG viewer using the wmode attribute. How do I do this in WebKit or Mozilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [A List Apart's article on SVG backgrounds](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-i/).

Comment: This is a great resource. Apparently the problem solves itself if you just use the <svg> tag directly in the HTML code. Make sure to use the .xhtml extension. http://emacsformacosx.com/ is a great example.

Answer (score 4):

Only webkit-based browsers fail to use a transparent background for `<object>` elements that reference svg in my experience. See for example the upper-right corner svg on my experimental site, [http://dahlström.net/](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/). Opera and Firefox work just fine without anything special needed, just view source and see.